# Cross domain json POST rails 3 rest service

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, jquery, http-post

How can i make a cross domain POST call for a rails 3 rest service.

I have read a lot about jsonp but its only for GET method. Are there any other way to do it on rails 3. Can anybody provide me with the exact steps to make a cross domain json POST call to rails rest service.

I want to make a POST call through ajax jquery to rails server side rest service.

I tried using JSONP but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Include POST as the type.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'ruby/file/name',
   data: {'foo': 'bar'},
   success: function(s) { 
     console.log('success' + s);
   },
   error: function(e) {
     console.log('error' + e);
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi this doesn't work as I am trying to make a cross domain post request. trying to make a jquery ajax Post call from domain1.com to a rail3 rest service on domain2.com

Comment: Crap... Not doable with JSONP, or client side scripting. You need to make the call server side. But the good thing is you can call a same domain server side script that posts cross domain data.

Comment: How can I do this  "call a same domain server side script that posts cross domain data" Can you please provide me the code on both jquery and rails side. The thing is that the html5 page is a phonegap app. I can't have any server side script on the phonegap. But my server is rails server that i need to post to

Comment: You would need rails running on both servers. I don't know rails enough to know the specific code, but this JQuery function is all you need client side.

Comment: Basically you have domain2.com listening for calls, and domain1.com listening and sending calls. The above code calls domain1.com's rails script that in turn posts it to domain2.com

Comment: The code you currently have for domin2.com should work for domain1.com with a slight mod that just forwards it to domain2.com instead of writing it on domain1.com

Comment: @user1025488, you could of course have the url have public information in it depending on what you're sending, but this does pose a security risk.